# Is it correct to say if any non-macro variable that is used in a conditional directive evaluates to 0?

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor, preprocessor-directive

Let's say I have the following piece of code. Is it correct to say that the conditional directive always evaluates to zero since `M` is expanded before compile time where the value of `i` is `zero` according to *C* specification? Could someone explain it if I'm wrong:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define M i

int main() {
    int i = 10;
    #if M == 0
     i = 0;
    #endif
    printf("%d", i);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `#if` identifiers that are not macros are all considered to be the number `zero`. The [gcc docs for #if](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/If.html) lay out the requirements nicel, which says (*emphasis mine going forward*):

```
#if expression
```

> expression is a C expression of integer type, subject to stringent restrictions. It may contain

- Integer constants.
- Character constants, which are interpreted as they would be in normal code.
- Arithmetic operators for addition, subtraction, multiplication, division, bitwise operations, shifts, comparisons, and logical operations (&& and ||). The latter two obey the usual short-circuiting rules of standard C.
- Macros. All macros in the expression are expanded before actual computation of the expression's value begins.
- Uses of the defined operator, which lets you check whether macros are defined in the middle of an ‘#if’.
- **Identifiers that are not macros, which are all considered to be the number zero.** This allows you to write #if MACRO instead of #ifdef MACRO, if you know that MACRO, when defined, will always have a nonzero value. Function-like macros used without their function call parentheses are also treated as zero.

and notes that:

> In some contexts this shortcut is undesirable. **The -Wundef option causes GCC to warn whenever it encounters an identifier which is not a macro in an ‘#if’**.

This is covered in the [draft C99 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) section `6.10.1` *Conditional inclusion* paragraph *4* which says:

> [...]After all replacements due to macro expansion and the defined unary
>   operator have been performed, **all remaining identifiers (including those lexically
>   identical to keywords) are replaced with the pp-number 0**, and then each preprocessing
>   token is converted into a token.[...]

Comment: So this means M always expands to 0, never i. Right? That's important for me to know if first it will expand to i then zero. Or, at the first place it will expand to zero.

Comment: @user3150474 that is how I understand it, if it is not a macro it will be replaced with a macro.

Comment: I meant to say replaced with zero.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they are treated as the number 0.

> #### C11 §6.10.1 Conditional inclusion
>
> ... After all replacements due to macro expansion and the defined unary operator have been performed, **all remaining identifiers (including those lexically identical to keywords) are replaced with the pp-number 0**, and then each preprocessing token is converted into a token.

*pp-number* here refers to *preprocessing numbers* in §6.4.8.